# why show me :8000 in my vircualhost in laragon?

Tags: laravel, virtualhost, laragon

in host file :

```
 #
    127.0.0.1 localhost
    ::1 localhost
    127.0.0.1      daily_tasks.local    #laragon magic!
```

D:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\auto.daily_tasks.local.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "D:/laragon/www/daily_tasks/public"
    ServerName daily_tasks.local
    ServerAlias *.daily_tasks.local
    <Directory "D:/laragon/www/daily_tasks/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# If you want to use SSL, enable it by going to Menu > Apache > SSL > Enabled
```

but whene run `php artisan serv` for run laravel. in browser this url `http://daily_tasks.local:8000/` is working!

I don't want it to be displayed `:8000` !

Comment: `php artisan serve` has nothing to do with apache2.

Comment: @tkausl. sorry i forget write for what. for run laravel.

Comment: Why are you using `php artisan serve` when you already have Laragon? Also, personal recommendation, don't use SSL locally, it is usually a pain to setup and adds no value to local environments

Comment: I think you're confusing `php artisan serve` which uses the built-in PHP interpreter with an Apache configuration. The default for `php artisan serve` is port 8000 so that will always be displayed in the browser. The default for Apache is port 80. You can't run Apache and have another server service on port 8000 because it will clash, so that's why the built-in PHP interpreter that Laravel uses defaults to port 8000.

The port is superficial, if you're running on localhost you're normally in development mode. But if for some reason you want to hide it, just try:

http://daily_tasks.local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laragon provides friendly url when the server is up. Only put your folder into `www` folder and restart Apache in Laragon, it'll detect a new project and that is all. You won't need `php artisan serve`.

DOCS: https://laragon.org/docs/pretty-urls.html

Answer (score 0):

how about proxy pass?

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ...
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).